# Angular material - mat-menu inside mat-toolbar

Tags: css, angular-material, material-design

I have simple mat-toolbar with simple button on the left and I want to put mat-menu on the right. Unfortunately I don't know why my right menu is cut and cannot fit entirely on the screen:

[image]

Between **Test** and **Robert** i have span element with flex:

```
<span class="space">/span>

.space{
   flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```